# Como abrir uma segunda janela no PyQt5 sem fechar a principal?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt-5

Estou criando uma interface de login, e quero que quando o usuário aperte um botão, abra uma nova janela no PyQt5 porém sem fechar a janela principal, mas a janela secundaria não está ficando aberta.

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

def ButtonClick():
    formSec = uic.loadUi("JanSec.ui")
    formSec.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
form = uic.loadUi("jan.ui")

form.Button.clicked.connect(ButtonClick)

form.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score -3):

Eu nunca usei o PyQt5 mas acredito que a lógica que eu uso para o tkinter funcionaria. você teria que criar dois "app" e chamar o segundo quando sua condição for atendida, no caso o apertar de um botão(espero ter ajudado :] )